# Resize virtual disk raid 0 MD1000 Perc 5/e

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc

I've created virtual disk raid 0 of total size 2TB (one physical hdd), what if I will want to add next 2TB hdd into my storage dell powervault MD1000? Can I resize my existing virtual disk without losing data?

Thanks :]

Comment: Are you familiar with the pitfalls of using RAID 0?

Comment: No I'm not, I just chosen the way of JBOD, dont need any extra mirror copies and so on :] But could you tell me more pls?

Comment: @EEAA RAID0 with 1 disk is Dell's version for JBOD. So there aren't really any pittfals here as it's not really RAID0.